# Как изменить регулярку в .htaccess для человекопонятых URL?

Tags: .htaccess, регулярные-выражения

У меня настроено в .htaccess ЧПУ

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ofise/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ofise.php?p=$1 [L]
```

При переходе на http://site.ru/ofise/nameofis мы попадаем на http://site.ru/ofise/ofise.php?p=nameofis и все работает

Как изменить регулярку, чтобы можно было принимать дополнительные GET в строку или хотя бы один? Так что бы и http://site.ru/ofise/nameofis?param=yes и http://site.ru/ofise/nameofis/?param=yes работали

Comment: @sayusha, м.б. имели ввиду человекопонятных? "Человекоподобных" звучит устрашающе.

Comment: @stck Да, как то я даже не вдумался, что написал :)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос почти решил. Нужно вместо [L] написать [QSA,L]

```
RewriteRule ^ofise/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ofise.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ofise/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ofise.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Проблема теперь в том, что адресу http://site.ru/ofise/nameofis все нормально, а по http://site.ru/ofise/nameofis/ не подгружаются стили,  а картинки работают нормально

Comment: Проблема решена добавлением абсолютного пути

Answer (score 1):

Для внешних стилей, js файлов, картинок и т.д. делай адреса относительно сервера, например -/images/img.png, а не относительно папки, потому как браузер воспринимает преобразованные URL как отдельные папки...